# TCP socket and Web Socket on playframework server?

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, netty, raw-sockets

My service already uses Websockets to communicate with an HTML5 in-browser client. The client is served by the same server from a normal http request.

Now I would like to offer the same service/app but out of the browser, and I would like to offer it over TCP sockets.

The RPCs/action object I am using are going to be the same, the serialization is going to be the same, the logic is the same. I just want to use TCP socket instead of WebSocket.

I would like to keep the code together under the same "project folder", starting all at once when I deploy the playframework server (basically on start I want to start listening to WebSockets, TCP sockets and http requests), and have everything in the same package on deploy.

I know that:

- It is not necessary, since WebSocket can be used in not-in-browser apps, but consider this an exercise or a curiosity question.
- playframework is built on top of netty, and I used netty before to do some TCP services (nothing big and nothing prod ready though ... so not an expert). So they should work together right?

What I was thinking to do:

1. Have an akka actor listen for new socket connections.
2. Wrap the connections (WS or TCP sockets) into a `ClientConnectionManager` instance
3. Pass it to the actors that takes care of the connections/rpc logic.

Other leads I considered: Reimplementing the playframework Controller class.

Or is there an already implemented solution for this?